# JavaFx: Context menu dynamic style

Tags: css, javafx, javafx-8, contextmenu, javafx-css

I have a problem with context menus. The items in the context menu can be styled, but it doesn't work dynamic. I mean for example at the initialize I add a styleclass to the `MenuItem` and by an event I remove it, but the style still remains there. How can it be solved?

Here is a simple example to play with it:

`Controller.java`:

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {

    private static final String STYLED = "styled";
    @FXML
    private ListView<String> listView;
    @FXML
    private Button change;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();

        MenuItem miAdd = new MenuItem("Add");
        miAdd.setOnAction(event -> listView.getItems().add("Apple"));

        MenuItem miRemove = new MenuItem("Remove");
        miRemove.disableProperty().bind(listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().isNull());
        miRemove.setOnAction(event -> listView.getItems().remove(listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()));
        cm.getItems().addAll(miAdd, miRemove);

        listView.setContextMenu(cm);
        miRemove.getStyleClass().add(STYLED);
        change.setOnAction(event -> {
            if (!miRemove.getStyleClass().contains(STYLED)) {
                miRemove.getStyleClass().add(STYLED);
            } else {
                miRemove.getStyleClass().remove(STYLED);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

`View.fxml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
            fx:controller="textField.Controller"
            stylesheets="css/layout.css">
    <VBox>
        <Button fx:id="change" text="ChangeStyle"/>
        <ListView fx:id="listView"/>
    </VBox>
</AnchorPane>
```

`layout.css`:

```
.styled .text {
    -fx-strikethrough: true;
}

.styled {
    -fx-background-color: gray;
}
```

How can I manage to add/remove style to my `MenuItem` ?

Comment: Well that's weird... Note that if you don't add the style class initially (i.e. comment out the line `miRemove.getStyleClass().add(STYLED);` that's *outside* of the handler), it all works as expected.

Comment: @James_D, my answer was based on a previously reported bug. You're right, when you comment `miRemove.getStyleClass().add(STYLED);`, it works just fine.

Comment: @M.S. can you add the bug #, please?

Comment: [this one](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8127435)

Comment: thanks @M.S. :) Might be a slightly different variant, as the bug is marked as fixed .. so maybe a follow-up report should be filed

Comment: @kleopatra Sorry, it’s my bad.

Comment: @James_D I tried also without that line, but still nothing happens, the style is not added to the `MenuItem`. I use java 1.8.0_121-b13.

Comment: @James_D have you tried does it works for you or it is a bug?

Comment: @Sunflame Yes: I ran it and it worked fine omitting that line; I'm using JavaFX 13 though.